# nodetool repair for "SYSTEM" and "OPSCENTER" keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh, nodetool

Do we also need to repair "SYSTEM" keyspaces and "OPSCENTER" keyspaces in Cassandra, along with the keyspaces we created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The answer is no and maybe respectively. Here's why:**

#### System KS

The SYSTEM keyspace uses Local replication strategy so there is no need or sense in repairing it -- remember, repair is an anti-entropy mechanism through which we ensure that multiple replicas on different nodes are holding the same, latest data. Because Local strategy means there is no replication, there is no need to build merkel trees and compare them.

#### OpsC KS

OpsCenter uses regular reads and writes into Cassandra to store information about your cluster health / statistics / etc. These will have multiple replicas and it is possible that different nodes may get out of sync (say one node is down for some reason and exceeds the max hint window).  In this case, you might see stale data if you're reading CL ONE from that node and a Repair would be beneficial. OpsC tables also have a TTL -- so you could see zombie data if for some reason tombstones don't get propagated across the cluster. But the impact of stale data in your OpsCenter statistics will not make or break your business.

So if you have the system resources to run repairs (hopefully using the OpsC repair service) on the OpsC keyspace, it won't hurt and might keep you from seeing stale data, etc. But turning these off for the OpsC keyspace may free up some system resources for your regular workload.